# How can I access the data of 3d digital weather clock wiget in android

Tags: android

There is a weather wiget in android phone having name "3D digital weather clock wiget" as shown in blue rectangle blow. I have problem how to read its data as show in RED rectangle in picture below. I wand to display the data in my application.

Please somebody help me. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you need to use whether service API...

please check http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/android-weather-forecast-google-weather-api-description-t337-30.html for more details and example.

See to get the London whather information you can pass http://www.google.bg/ig/api?weather=London,ES&hl=en in request and in result you will get XML that you need to parse and then show.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thnx dear I have downloaded the source code but there are some files are missing do you have any idea how to run the proj

Comment: Ya I understand but there is some complex code. Now I want arrange the project files just to run code